# Change audio being played with delay android

Tags: android, audio, media, playback

I am trying to run audios one after another with a time gap of 5 seconds. However I dont really see that happening. My third audio in the list is played and others are skipped. This means while debugging only music3 is being played and others are not. I would love alternate methods of doing this. Moreover I used prepare method just like that. Makes no difference while running though.

```
for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
{

    if(j==0)
        {
        xnp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ticktock);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                xnp.prepare();
                xnp.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }, 5000);

        xnp.stop();
        }
    if(j==1)
        {
        xnp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.music2);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                xnp.prepare();
                xnp.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }, 5000);

        xnp.stop();
        }
    else if (j==2)
        {
        xnp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.music3);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    xnp.prepare();
                    xnp.start();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            }, 5000);
        xnp.stop();
        intenter();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation does not work because the media playback is not done on the main thread, so you are immediately playing all 3 media resources, so only the third one is heard.

I think you might want to call [MediaPlayer#setOnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) on your MediaPlayer object. In the completion listener, you can then postDelayed onto your Handler to queue up the next resource to play.

Comment: You mean like this:
 for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
 {

  if(j==0)
   {
   xnp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ticktock);
   xnp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp) {

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     
      xnp.start();
     
    }
    }, 5000);
   xnp.release();
   intenter();
    }
    });
   }